# Image to binary string

Tags: string, image, binary

I need this for a scriptUI panel I am working on. I am trying to add a custom image button and the image to be part of the jsx file.
Does somebody know how this kind binary string is achieved, and how do I turn a png file to string of that type '\u0089PNG....' (is it initially Base64 encoded and then another encoding, or is it an encoded Byte array):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS8oy.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That doesn't look like a Base64 encoding; it's just a plain binary PNG file. But why are you using a screenshot to show the code? Why not show the code itself here in the post?

Comment: Because I am trying to implement my own image and I don't know how to achieve this binary string. This is just a screenshot from a video I found. I don't have problem with creating the button itself on the panel, it's just the image data that needs to be applied

Comment: So your question really is, "how do I turn a PNG file into a string of the form `"\u0089PNG` etc?" That wasn't very clear.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution using ExtendScript Toolkit

```
var img = File("1.png");
img.open('r');
img.encoding = 'BINARY';
var imgstr = img.read();
img.close();

$.writeln(imgstr.toSource());
```

It reads the PNG image and outputs the string in the console.

Thanks!